# Function chaining with function names from list

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, chaining

Is there a way to get a function name from an list and use it inside a function chain? NOT as a value, but as the name itself.

This:

```
var funcList = ['funcNameA', 'funcNameB', 'funcNameC'];
Interface.methods.funcList[0]().call();
```

Should be equal to:

```
Interface.methods.funcNameA().call();
```

**EDIT:**
Also what would be the way if I wanted to put the function name from the list at the beginning of a function chain?

Comment: Why does `funcList` need to hold strings? Why don't you add the actual names?

Comment: This just screams `eval()`, how are you constructing that array?

Comment: `Interface.methods[funcList[0]]();` will execute the function named in element 0 of the array.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown we don't know that `funcNameA` doesn't return a function.